# Object constructor syntax error

Tags: javascript

In the process of learning JS... it's mai second week from the first day of JS and i have that big problems with syntax

```
function Customer(name, street, city, state, email, balance) {
    this.name = name;
    this.street = street;
    this.city = city;
    this.state = state;
    this.email = email;
    this.balance = balance;
    this.payDownBal = function(amtPaid) {
        this.balance -= amtPaid;
    };
    this.addToBa = function(amtCharged) {
        this.balance += amtCharged;
    };
}
var cust2 = new Customer("Sally Smith", "234 Main ", "Pittsburgh", "PA", "ssmith@aol.com", 0.00);

cust2.addToBal(15.50);

Customer.prototype.isCreditAvail = true;

Customer.prototype.toString = function() {
    return this.name + " lives at " + this.street + " in " +
        this.city + " " + this.state + " email : " + this.email +
        " and has a balance of $ " + this.balance.toFixed(2) + "Creditworty : " + this.isCredAvail;
}
document.write(cust2.toString());
```

I can't find the error...can i be helped please ?

Comment: What makes you think there is an error? Did you get an error message? If so what is it? Stack Overflow is not a place where you can just post a big chunk of code and expect others to fix it for you. Explain the issue and provide relevant information. See [ask].

Comment: next post it will be more specified , thanks for your advices

Comment: You don't have to wait till your next post, you can [edit] this one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a simple mistake.
You defined *addToBa()* function and you are calling function *addToBal()* which is not defined.

Change the line 17 to call the function *addToBa()*. (or change the function declaration to *addToBal()*).

Answer (score 1):

Well, look at line 11 closely, your function declaration:

```
this.addToBa = function (amtCharged) {
```

and line 17:

```
cust2.addToBal(15.50);
```

It's a typo, "addToBa" on line 11 should be "addToBal".

(Also, there's another typo that won't allow the "isCreditAvail" TRUE boolean value to be referenced in your toString function, on the 3rd-to-last line... change "this.isCredAvail" to "this.isCreditAvail").